# Any way to differentiate between those two functions?

Tags: python, numpy

So far, I've seen functions, in numpy for example, where you just apply the function to a certain object/variable. And the result is automatically assigned to that object without you asking for it. 
Example: `np.random.shuffle(a)`. The answer will be stored in a even if you don't ask for that. How can you tell if a certain function does this in-place action or does it act like a normal function do.
Thanks.

Comment: While it's true that many member methods alter the internal attributes of their parent object, the return value of a method is never **automatically** assigned to anything.

Comment: You might call that *mutator* vs. *accessor* methods. Mutators mutate (change) the object, while accessors just return data.

Comment: Also *inplace* operations should be mentioned here

Comment: Sorry, I think I have mistakenly thought of it as a method. It is actually a function.
Neverthless, it is still weird that it replace the objection without me assigning it to the object. Example: np.random.shuffle(a). a gets replaced without me asking.

Comment: *"How can you tell if a certain function does this?"* You read the docs.

Comment: `shuffle` doesn't *replace* `a`, it *mutates* it.

Comment: Reading docs, sure. I thought there's something special that distinguishes them right away. Thank you any way. 
But, one more thing, suppose I wanted the result to be stored in a different variable? What should I do? I'm trying it now and it is not working.

Comment: Make a copy of `a` and then call the function on the copied object.

Comment: Got it. Thank you all.

Comment: About your specific example. [`np.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) explicitly states in the docs it modifies the sequence in place, and it returns nothing, so you cannot mistakenly think you got a new object as a result. If you want to shuffle a NumPy array not in-place, you can, as suggested, make a copy and shuffle, or do something like `array[np.random.permutation(len(array))]`. About "something special that distinguishes them", while some languages (e.g. C++) provide something like that, there is nothing like that in Python.

Comment: @jdehesa Genius. Exactly the explanation that I wanted. So, the bottom line is, because they don't return anything, you can tell right away that they do in-place mutation and you cannot mistake them for a regular function. Thank you so very much.